# java execute script in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, rest, shell, tomcat

I created a spring boot project, which I'm running on a local tomcat (I'm planning to deploy this to a webserver). Within this project I created a rest-service, which should execute a .bat file.

my rest services look like this (neither of them works)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/esc", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String esc() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String folder = "P:\\Documents\\testcmd";
    String[] cmdarray = new String[]{"cmd -c","dosomething.cmd"};
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( cmdarray );
    processBuilder.directory(new File(folder));
    Process process = processBuilder.start();

    int exitCode = -1;
    boolean finished = false;
    while ( !finished ) {
        exitCode = process.waitFor();
        finished = true;
    }
    return folder;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ex", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String executeShellScript(){
    //final String shCmd = "/bin/bash -c helloworld.sh";
    System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
            System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    final String shCmd = "cmd -c P:/Documents/testcmd/dosomething.cmd";
    String output = executeCommand(shCmd);

    return output;
}
private String executeCommand(String command){
    Process p;
    InputStream in = null;
    String value = "";
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        in = p.getInputStream();
        int ch;
        while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
            value = String.valueOf((char)ch);
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;
}
```

I tried it with a processbuilder and with runtime.
The file I want to execute is in this folder: "P:\Documents\testcmd"

Is it even possible to execute a local file with a tomcat server?

Comment: Are you running on Windows or Linux ? (it's unclear as you call _/bin/bash_ and _cmd -c_ )

Comment: i am running this on windows

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. The sollution with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` was correct. Only my system call was wrong. Instead of `final String shCmd = "cmd -c P:/Documents/testcmd/dosomething.cmd";` I had to use `"P:/Documents/testcmd/dosomething.cmd"`. In addition I had to change the `dosomething.cmd` because it was wrong. When executing the plain java code, the file would open a cmd terminal and then print hello in an endless loop. I changed the file content that instead of the endless loop in the terminal it prints hello into another file.

```
// method is mapped on root/ex
@RequestMapping(value = "/ex", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String executeShellScript(){
    System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
            System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    final String shCmd = "P:\\Documents\\testcmd\\dosomething.cmd -c";
    String output = executeCommand(shCmd);

    return output;
}
```

batch file before  & after

```
@echo off
:start
echo hallo
pause
goto start
```

after

```
@echo off
@echo This is a test>> P:/Documents/testcmd/file.txt
@echo 123>> P:/Documents/testcmd/file.txt
@echo 245.67>> P:/Documents/testcmd/file.txt
```